# Disable sorting when clicking DataGridView column header

Tags: c#

I have a `DataGridView` column header. When I click that header, the data is resorted according to the value.

I don't want that.

`DataGrid` has an `AllowSort` property. DataGridView doesn't have that. Anything I can do?

Comment: I am pretty sure it does has such a property. `AllowUserToSort` or `ColumnHeaderStyle`. I'll confirm when I get to work. I use this quite a lot.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can override OnColumnAdded function:

```
 protected override void OnColumnAdded(DataGridViewColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnColumnAdded(e);
        e.Column.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
    }
```

Comment: Or handle the ColumnAdded event, which is probably nicer since it doesn't require subclassing the DGV.

Comment: yea.. that's working.. but for beginners,

for (int i = 0; i < DGV1.ColumnCount; i++)
            {
                DGV1.Columns[i].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
            }

Answer (score 18):

You can disable auto sort for each and every individual cells in your DataGridView:

[image]

Answer (score 16):

You have to set that on the columns. For example,

```
dataGridView1.Columns["MyColumn"].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void dataGridView1_ColumnAdded(object sender, DataGridViewColumnEventArgs e)
{            
    e.Column.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
}
```