# Best way to disable the column header sorting in DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I need to disable the column header sorting in `DataGridView`.

We can do that by setting the property of individual columns like

```
BalancesGridView.Columns[1].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
```

If this is the case , then I'll have to loop through all the columns.

Is there a better way ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, I think setting the SortMode on the column directly is as good as it gets. But honestly, who cares? What's so bad about a simple loop?

Comment: there is a little problem with looping to set the individual column sortmode, for example, you allow user to add more columns, then you have to re-loop it all again, or find the added column and set it's sortmode. that is a bit of more work (for case of re-looping, in an impossible extreme case of adding a single columns to an already thousands of columns existed, that would be time consuming)

Answer (score 13):

What's so bad about this? If it bothers you to loop over the columns or you have multiple DataGridView's, you can write an extension method for this:

```
public static class DatatGridViewExtensions
{
    public static void SetColumnSortMode(this DataGridView dataGridView, DataGridViewColumnSortMode sortMode)
    {
        foreach (var column in dataGridView.Columns)
        {
            column.SortMode = sortMode;
        }
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
BalancesGridView.SetColumnSortMode(DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable);
```

Comment: This doesn't really achieve anything. This makes all columns in the datagridview not sortable. The extension method itself isn't a bad idea, but it's incomplete. It needs to have another parameter and maybe even an overload to allow a column id, column name or a collection of either to be passed in.

Comment: @Joel Etherton: Read his question again. The OP want's to disable column header sorting in general.

Comment: got it to work with a slight modification:         

public static void SetColumnSortMode(this DataGridView dataGridView, DataGridViewColumnSortMode sortMode)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewTextBoxColumn column in dataGridView.Columns) { dataGridView.Columns[column.Name].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable; } 
        }

Answer (score 8):

I don't know why nobody suggest you Linq way of doing this:

```
BalancesGridView.Columns.Cast<DataGridViewColumn>().ToList().ForEach(f => f.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable);
```

Comment: This doesn't really helps with the performance. Just makes the code short.

Answer (score 5):

I say looping through columns is not such a great answer, especially if your datasource is changing from time to time.  One line of code in the ColumnAdded event does the trick:

```
e.Column.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
```

Answer (score 4):

well, this is a bit old, but there is a little problem with looping to set the individual column sortmode, for example, you allow user to add more columns, then you have to re-loop it all again, or find the added column and set it's sortmode. that is a bit of more work.

the solution I found is like this link: [Disable sorting when clicking DataGridView column header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965304/disable-sorting-when-clicking-datagridview-column-header)

in it, you just add an event handler of ColumnAdded for that DataGridView, so every time the datagrid adds column, it is automatically set as not sortable

this is actually just like @OldDog's answer, the difference is that in his answer, the sortmode is set in a roundabout way.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_ColumnAdded(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewColumnEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.ColumnAdded
    e.Column.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this problem today.  I wrote this method and called it on the form load event.

```
    public void DisableGridviewSorting(DataGridView grid, int index)
    {
        //Index = DataGridView.Columns.Count
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
        {
            grid.Columns[i].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
        }
    }
```

It looks like you are pretty much stuck looping through the DataGridView no matter how you do it, unless you use bound data.  Then you can set non-sortable for each individual column.

Answer (score 2):

If you build the DataGridView at runtime, you can disable column sorting as the columns are added using the ColumnAdded Event:

```
private void BalancesGridView_ColumnAdded(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnEventArgs e)
{
     e.Column.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have done it in this way:

```
private void gvItReq_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
{
    for (int colIdx = 0; colIdx < gvItReq.Columns.Count; colIdx++)
        gvItReq.Columns[colIdx].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: It will work but this is a bad way to do it. For each row added you will set the sortmode of the same column again and again and again...

Answer (score 0):

In VB I use a little subroutine I call for each dgv where I want the columns to be unsortable:

```
Public Sub subNo_Sort_DGV_Columns(dgv As DataGridView)

  For intColumn_Count As Integer = 1 To dgv.Columns.Count - 1
    dgv.Columns(intColumn_Count).SortMode = _ DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
  Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way I've found to prevent sorting is to define is to define it a for loop when you think you have to many columns to deal with.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   dataGridView.Columns[i].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
}
```

Comment: what if column length is less than 10?   This will throw an exception.

Comment: poor example of a loop and the author of the question specifically asked for an alternate to a loop. also just adding clutter to the Q&A