# windows forms datagridview sorting and paging

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Windows Form DataGridView loading only the page size from the database. If I click a column header it will only sort the displayed records.

How do I sort the column relative to all records in the result set (displayed and not displayed)?

My SQL handles sorting, I just need to override the DataGridView's sorting, call my SQL with a sort column and display the records?

Comment: If you are looking to disable column header sorting on the data grid then you may take a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334983/best-way-to-disable-the-column-header-sorting-in-datagridview

Comment: Out of curiosity, from a UX perspective, why are you paginating a winforms DataGridView?

Comment: @lc. What if the resultset has a large amount records to load from the database? Am I thinking about it the wrong way?

Comment: @Rod Maybe it's just me but I've never really seen a windows application with paginated data. As the web experience and desktop experience converge though, it could be ok. Was just a question to make sure you're solving the right problem :)

Comment: +1 for lc. Still if you want to do it, answer is Yes.