# C# DataGridView (DataSet source) Column SortMode resets when changing DataMember

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, dataset

***TL;DR***: When changing DataMember tables in a DataSet bound to a DataGridView with NotSortable column SortMode and ColumnSelect SelectionMode, an InvalidOperationException is thrown because the SortMode appears as "Automatic".

I have implemented an Excel input feature into my app, and I'm using the [ExcelDataReader](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader) package from NuGet to do so. This is reading my Excel files and converting them into DataSet as expected.

However, when I tried to bind that DataSet to a DataGridView, with the intention of allowing the user to "select" what cells/columns/rows to use, I received the error the following InvalidOperationException when enabling Column selection mode:

```
 Column's SortMode cannot be set to Automatic while the DataGridView control's SelectionMode is set to ColumnHeaderSelect.
```

This was solved using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4335035/2664719) on another question, which works as expected on initial bind.

**However**, the Excel spreadsheet may have multiple Worksheets, so I have displayed them using a ComboSelectBox -- and on SelectionChangeCommitted, I am changing the DataGridView's DataMember to the index of the selected Worksheet.

On this change I am still getting the InvalidOperationException above, even though I am repeating the exact same code as in the initial bind -- that is working correctly.

**So question is, how can I stop the SortMode from apparently being reset to Automatic or get the same code that's working for the initial Bind to work on the DataMember change.**

Thanks :)

**ExcelForm.cs**

```
// This works fine on initial Bind, no errors
private void PrepareUI()
{
  // DataGridView dataGridContents
  dataGridContents.DataSource = _contents;
  dataGridContents.DataMember = _contents.Tables[0].TableName;
  dataGridContents.SetColumnSortMode(DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable);
  dataGridContents.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.ColumnHeaderSelect;

  DataTable worksheets = GetWorksheetValues(_contents);

  comboWorksheet.DataSource = worksheets;
  comboWorksheet.ValueMember = "index";
  comboWorksheet.DisplayMember = "name";
}

// On SelectionChangeCommitted, same code -- but throws an InvalidOperationException
private void comboWorksheet_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  dataGridContents.DataMember = _contents.Tables[int.Parse(((ComboBox)sender).SelectedValue.ToString())].TableName;
  dataGridContents.SetColumnSortMode(DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable);
  dataGridContents.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.ColumnHeaderSelect;
}
```

**DataGridViewExtensions.cs**

```
static class DataGridViewExtensions
{
    public static void SetColumnSortMode(this DataGridView dataGridView, DataGridViewColumnSortMode sortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn c in dataGridView.Columns)
        {
            c.SortMode = sortMode;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Update: I tried adding the .SetColumnSortMode and .SelectionMode functions into a DataMemberChanged event handler, but this didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, in my SelectionChangeCommitted eventHandler I simply changed the DataGridView SelectionMode back to RowHeaderSelect before changing the DataMember, and then my DataMemberChanged eventHandler changes it back again to ColumnHeaderSelect.

```
    private void comboWorksheet_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridContents.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.RowHeaderSelect;
        dataGridContents.DataMember = _contents.Tables[int.Parse(((ComboBox)sender).SelectedValue.ToString())].TableName;
    }

    private void dataGridContents_DataMemberChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridContents.SetColumnSortMode(DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable);
        dataGridContents.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.ColumnHeaderSelect;
    }
```

I feel like this is messy, but it works.